# how to get width of divs after change vuejs

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to change the width of a div on basis of another div.

[image]

The above scroll is the div which width will get change on the basis of below table width.

I have implemented this method as mixin in Vue.

```
    Vue.mixin({
      methods: {
        setScrollBar: () => {
          Vue.nextTick().then(function () {
            let tableWidth = document.querySelector("table.vuetable").offsetWidth;
            let tableWrapper = document.querySelector("div.vuetable-body-wrapper").offsetWidth;
            console.log(tableWidth)
            console.log(tableWrapper)

            document.querySelector("div.top-horizontal-scroll").style.width = tableWidth + "px";
            document.querySelector("div.top-scrollbar").style.width = tableWrapper + "px"
          });
        }
      }
})
```

When the button on the top left, clicked, to close the menu it gives the width of the table but just on clicked, I want to get the width of the table after fully changed.

at first, the tableWidth and tableWrapper are of 2714 and 1677 px.
after the click, it should change to 2714 and 1877.

but on click, it gives the last width, not the changed one.

On menu click i have set this method

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    setScroll()  {
      console.log("called")
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.setScrollBar()
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This gets called but on each click width is the very first one not changed one.

[image]

Comment: Could you please build a working example of the issue possibly on https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I thnk not its not possible to create such setup sorry

Comment: I simply want to get a div width after it resized completely

Comment: Why wouldn't your div be part of your table container, it'll have the same width as its parent automatically.

Comment: automatically? realy?